Karnaugh map minimization confusion
I'm given a Karnaugh diagram like below. And the correct way to circle the elements. I learned that when two elements are at the edges of a diagram they wrap around. So my question is why do we not do wrap around for first and last elements of first row like visualized in the last image? And same with first and last element of third row? Why are the last elements circled by themselves instead?



Your observation is correct.
The first diagram will result in a correct expression, but your solution is a little more efficient. The number of terms for the expression will be the same in both (as this equals the circled "blocks") but in your diagram two terms will be shorter (larger blocks give shorter terms).

Thank you. I did notice that when using varying solutions for similar problems, that they can all get simplified to the same expression. But with this problem I can't show they are equal to each other. Wiith textbook solution I get $z'w' + x'yzw+xy'zw+x'y'zw+xyzw'$. While with my solution $z'w' + x'yzw+xy'zw+x'y'w+xyw'$. If they are equal, how can we simplify away z in the fourth and fifth term?

That's a different question. Are your primes correct?
